# Java 8 Stream with GroupBy With Collectors.summarizingInt()

Tags: java, java-8, group-by, java-stream

I have a question from running this code.

```
private void groupingByMethod(final List<Integer>values){
    //I THOUGHT THAT e was a List but is a int already  
    final ToIntFunction<Integer>summingFunction = e->{
        return e;
    };
    values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),Collectors.summarizingInt(summingFunction))))
            .forEach((a,b)->System.out.println(a+" "+b));
}
```

If I'm running a test this code with data.

```
private final List<Integer>data = Arrays.asList(3,3,1,2,4);
```

I get the data I'm expecting.

```
1 IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=1, min=1, average=1,000000, max=1}
2 IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=2, min=2, average=2,000000, max=2}
3 IntSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=6, min=3, average=3,000000, max=3}
4 IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=4, min=4, average=4,000000, max=4}
```

Of course in my code, I am using a nested Collectors.collectingAndThen but is the same. it's for making the code simpler.

So everything is working like a charm so what's the problem right?

My question is the parameter to

```
 Collectors.summarizingInt(summingFunction)
```

I know that Collectors.summarizingInt is expecting a **toIntFunction** so where this value comes from I know also that is the size of the Array so how java can know I'm expecting this value? I was expecting a List value as a parameter so I can do a simply **List::size** so this is more understandable for my the group generates a List so the list itself is passed as a parameter and you do want you want to it but is the **.size()** already

Can somebody guide me on this stuff? Perhaps is not list.size()? if so how the count value is computed?

Comment: `map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1))));`

Comment: i have a stream of Map.Entries?

Comment: Do not use a List as the key of a map (unless the list is immutable). Otherwise you will get a bunch of problems that are difficult to understand and hard to debug.

Comment: _...where this value come from i know also that is the size of the Array..._ No it isn't size of array, but it's each element of array.

Comment: What's the point of `Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), ...)`?